# y-axis with date

Tags: ssrs-2008

i have a graph to plot, with dates in each axis, in x axis i have a date that represent the date pictures of taks was taken, and in the y-axis i would like to put the finish dates of that task, my query returns something like this
Task         PictureDate     FinishDate
A            01-03-2010      20-05-2010
A            08-03-2010      20-05-2010
A            15-03-2010      22-05-2010
B            01-03-2010      12-06-2010
B            08-03-2010      13-06-2010
B            15-03-2010      14-06-2010

I can not put the Finishdate in y-axis, is there a workaround i can use to display y-axis label as date?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it could apply for this, but in .Net we can use a DateTime as a double by doing.

```
Datetime dt = new DateTime()
double l = dt.toOADate();
dt = Datetime.FromOADate(double l);
```

Maybe by giving a format or axistype or something like this you can do it.